# 2 OS(Windows 10/Linux) 1 PC simultaneous with 2 keyboard/mice and 4 monitor

Tags: linux, windows, multiple-monitors, hyper-v

I'm using dual boot to switch from work to gaming which is troublesome.
I would like to have both OS running at the same time and the Linux one use my iGPU (worst case scenario I could get another dedicated card) and windows use my dedicated GPU.

Basically I thought I might setup a Hyper-V VM and pass through the iGPU and some of the USB ports but I have no idea how.

Comment: This article about Hyper-V may assist you:  https://searchvirtualdesktop.techtarget.com/tip/Running-GPU-passthrough-for-a-virtual-desktop-with-Hyper-V

Comment: IMHO, WSL makes this pointless.  Run them both.  *TRY IT*, you will be amazed.  Start with WSL1 and only if you need it (you will know), move to WSL2.